# How can I create a data toggle with HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I posted a link to the picture of the layout I am working on. I do not have any experience with jQuery and JavaScript; so is there a way I can create a data toggle like this with pure HTML/CSS3 ?

[image]

Comment: dont understand ur question

Comment: Is it that you want to change the data in the bottom block based on which of the 3 buttons is clicked?

Comment: I mean that when i click on one of the buttons, there will be an overlay layer appear on top of the buttons panel showing other content & elements. If i want to go back to the buttons panel, i will click the 'X' icon at the left top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way with pure CSS because css pseudo-classes just allow You to check if the button is active so like when you are pressing it try this and keep it pressed:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b152op5w/3/)

You can give to all buttons a different id for example #button1, #button2, #button3

and to the filters also different ones #filter1, #filter2, #filter3

And then in Your css do something like this

```
#button1:active ~ #filter1 {
 //your changes to the css
}
```

but this is just temporary, if You really dont want to use JQuery so You can try to use checkboxes and style them in a better way to fit your needs and then use the ':checked' pseudo-class

Like [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bk32wsLe/)

For the close button You will not make it with only css, if You want I can give You the JQuery code :)

Comment: Would You mark it as solved or vote it up please? :)